# How to synchronize data between model and view (2 ways) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

I try to use jQuery plugins like chain.js or DataBind, but it is not quite what I need...

Chain.js can't store changed data to the model (as I know).
DataBind have method `unbinddata()`, that store changed data in JSON structure, but can work only with form inputs, not with attributes or `$(el).data()`.

Comment: Oooo boy, you should check out live data binding in ASP.NET Ajax 4. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819084.aspx See "Two way data binding" (near the middle).

Comment: Check out the MS proposed Data Linking solution [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/proposal-for-adding-data-linking-to-jquery) or about halfway down [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx)

Comment: @AdmSteck: oh wow, interesting. I hate the proposed syntax though. Funneling even more functionality through `$` is just silly. I mean, `$({foo:"bar"}).linkFrom(...)`?? Please nooooo